# Clamping an object axis in Vuforia AR camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBgeq.png)I want to clamp Y-axis on a cube. I can do it in Unity camera. But, it does not react correctly when I am using it in Vuforia camera.
My problem was that the cube follows the camera. I would like the cube to stay in its position and ignore the AR camera position. I sense it has something to do with WorldtoViewpoint but I cannot figure it out. Can you teach me how to do this please?   thankyou

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ClampMovementController : MonoBehaviour
{


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Vector3 pos = transform.localPosition;
        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, 0f, 0f);
        transform.localPosition = pos;
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you create that cube? Is it anchored to a `Trackable` if not it is expected behavior.

Comment: Yes. objects are attached to the image target. Would it be easier to solve this problem if i told you I am using lean touch1.6? and I would like to move x, z position when lean touch register my finger drag.

Comment: Well i do not think it is related to that. Can you share screenshot of your hierarchy with image target. Also do you have an empty game object as parent of the cube?

Comment: I have added a screenshot link in my question... Hierarchy is a cube inside capsule inside image target.  Please add a script to lock any movement on capsule Y axis, which means user only can move the capsule X and Z axis only, . Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:
Actually its very simple. The INcorrect concept was my object attached to the AR camera, hence, object position is always moving related to camera position. Now. In order to make the object stays in its place. I need to get its localPosition. First. Store the localposition in Vector3 pos. And then do modification on Vector3 pos. At last, reassign the new value to the object localposition.

```
public class ClampMovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float currentPos;
    public GameObject capsule;

    void Update()
    {
        //store the value of object localPosition
        Vector3 pos = capsule.transform.localPosition;
        //modification on the value
        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, currentPos, currentPos);
        //rerassign the new value to the object localPosition
        capsule.transform.localPosition = pos;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your cube is moving with the camera because your image target is child of your ARCamera. Therefore, when you move the camera image target moves, then your cube moves as well. Make sure your `ImageTarget` has no parent.

I did not understand why you **have to** lock any movement in Y axis. I guess you are doing something wrong with lean touch when you move object. I have not used lean touch but i have achieved this with keyboard inputs. You can convert it to lean touch by modifying following script. Just add these line to your `ImageTarget`'s `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` script:

```
//Variables for getting capsule and checking if ImageTarget is tracked
private bool isTracked = false;
private GameObject capsule;
```

Then create an `Update` method for getting input from user like this.

```
 void Update()
{
    if(isTracked)
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            //using forward for moving object in z axis only. 
            //Also using local position since you need movement to be relative to image target
            //Global forward can be very different depending on your World Center Mode
            capsule.transform.localPosition += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            capsule.transform.localPosition -= Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            //Using Vector3.left and right to be make sure movement is in X axis.
            capsule.transform.localPosition += Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            capsule.transform.localPosition += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no movement in Y axis because i used forward, left and right vectors to make sure movement in in only X and Y axis.

Last you have to make sure `isTracked` is updated. In order to do that you have to add `isTracked = false;` in `OnTrackingLost` method and `isTracked = true;` in `OnTrackingFound` method. Good luck!

Comment: Thankyou so much @Ali Kanat ...  Your solution inspire my understanding of localPosition.  I will be delighted If you could write couple more words on explaining when to use localPosition VS transform.position. Thanks again.